# MySQL design multi outlet products

Tags: mysql, database, database-schema

A company has many products. It has many stores. Each store has different price and inventory to track.

My current DB Design is:

Products

```
ID product_name price inventory
```

Stores

```
ID store_name
```

ProductAttr

```
store_id product_id price inventory
```

Now I am saving the inventory and price in product table itself in case a new product is added in one of the stores and the ProductAttr table row is not created for other stores, in which case they can default to products table.

Is it better to have the attributes move to ProductAttr table completely. If they add a new store in few weeks time, I need to make sure all product attributes are created under this new store. Also when a store creates a product, to create rows for all the stores.

What would be the best approach to tackle this kind of situation?

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking along the correct line.  The `inventory` attribute should belong to `ProductAttr` as its a property related to that store's product.

You can futher add a `default store`, which can be assigned in case you don't have stores to assign.

The total product inventory will be the sum of inventory in `ProductAttr` table.

Comment: Is it better practice to insert rows for all stores in ProductAttr table in product creation? Also if a new store is added, it needs to have rows for it too? This is the bit I am concerned about.

Comment: Yes, you need to insert rows in ProductAttr.  Same goes for new stores.  This is correct way and this is how its done in relational databases !